# How do I point to a .php file that is in another folder?

Tags: php, html

My file "index.php" has the script below:

```
<?php

$pagina = empty($_GET['p']) ? 'home' : $_GET['p'];

switch ($pagina):
  case 'contato':
    $titulo = 'Contato ';
    $keywords = '';
    $descricao = '';
    break;

case 'privacidade':
    $titulo = 'Privacidade ';
    $keywords = '';
    $descricao = '';
    break;

case 'ultimasnoticias':
    $titulo = 'Ultimas Noticias';
    $keywords = '';
    $descricao = '';
    break;

default:
    $titulo = 'Home';
    $keywords = '';
    $descricao = '';
    $pagina = 'home';
endswitch;
?>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $titulo; ?></title>
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keywords; ?>">
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $descricao; ?>">
</head>
<body>

<?php require_once 'page_' . $pagina . '.php'; ?>

<footer>Rodapé</footer>
</body>
</header>
```

I had some problems trying to explain my problem, my English is really bad, so I will try to explain what I need with the image below.

[image: my image]

Comment: Welcome. What doesn't work? (And `</header>` should be `</html>`)

Comment: Your question isn't clear. i thin in the <a> tag you need something like this, href="posts/name_page"

Comment: take all your fingers but the index one, fold them over, like you are making a fist (except leave that index finger unbent) then point at your screen.  Seriously, you would/should set a path constant, or use `__DIR__` and then you can make the paths relative too the location the current script is running at.  Such as `__DIR__./posts/`

Comment: @kerbholz Hello, yes you're right, but fixed it. I need to access the .php files that are into the folder "posts". You will see more details on the image that i put in the question.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix lol but, could you tell me how to do what you said to me? I'm new in PHP

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="posts/your_page.php"></a>
```

If you want to go in parent folder use "../"

For include:

```
include 'posts/your_page.php';
```

I edit but not sure it's what you want:

Your page is me.php, you can do:

```
include_once 'views/inc/header.php';
include_once 'views/me.php';
include_once 'views/inc/footer.php';
```

The header start with `<!DOCTYPE html>` end with `<body>`
Your footer is like : `</body></html>`

Comment: No, i need to include my file into my index.php, so i need to use ?p=archiveName, But i dont know how to include the file that are into the folder "posts" to the file "index.php". I'm new in PHP.

Comment: include 'posts/your_page.php'; then

Comment: I cant just include my file into index.php, i need a comand line like this `<?php require_once 'page_' . $pagina . '.php'; ?>` on my `body` tag. I think you're not understanding what is my problem, i'm using 1 file just for the header and footer, so i need a "php code" to put into my `body` tag to access the files that are into my folder "posts".

Comment: Yes sir. you got it. As you see on my script, i have a code to load the _files_ between the Header and Footer, but my code can load only the files that are in the  main directory, and i need to load the files that are in the folder "posts" too.

Comment: Actually I was answering your question, im going to test your code soon.

Comment: it wont work `include_once 'views/me.php';` it will only work if i wanted to see only one page, instead of that i need to set a a path like this `<?php require_once 'page_' . $pagina . '.php'; ?>` to get my files.

Comment: I think I got it. Why you don't write this: $titulo = 'Contato ';
    $keywords = '';
    $descricao = ''; In all your files instead

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to a file in sub-directories from a PHP file in the parent ones by using

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

This function gives you the current working directory i.e where the current running PHP file is in, now relative to this directory you can access a PHP file like:

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . "/subdirectory/myphpfile.php"
```

Comment: Could you said where do i put this line dirname(__FILE__)? and include dirname(__FILE__). I'm new in PHP.

Comment: you put it where you want the other file included at.